# Effect called when humans overvalue one good event after series of Bad events and Overexaggeration one single bad event after series of Good events

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, expressions, proverbs

What is the effect called on humans when

When you have seen series of bad events happen to you, and then the next  tend to overvalue an negligible good thing happening as a gratitude or grand success or preciously value it

Similarly

When you have seen good events (things) happening to you, you tend to over-exaggerate (have negative effect for) an negligible negative thing happening as a insult or grand failure (you just can't digest it)

Comment: "Human nature".

Answer (score 2):

Overvaluing the last (most recent) effect is **recency** bias.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recency_bias): Recency bias is a cognitive bias that favors recent events over historic ones. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recency_bias)

Comment: This would benefit from a link to the appropriate Wikipedia article.

Answer (score 1):

This is called the [contrast effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contrast_effect).

From Wikipedia:

> A contrast effect is the enhancement or diminishment, relative to normal, of perception, cognition or related performance as a result of successive (immediately previous) or simultaneous exposure to a stimulus of lesser or greater value in the same dimension.

Answer (score 0):

You are describing a *Cognitive Bias*, as described in *Thinking, Fast and Slow* by Daniel Kahneman.

One of the biases is called *Loss Aversion*.

> **Loss Aversion**
>
> Say you’ve just lost $50 gambling but have a 50% chance of winning it back, you would be more inclined to try again. Because you’re already in $50 deep. This is how many people get sunken into gambling loopholes.

([Source](https://eeshau.medium.com/cognitive-biases-to-watchout-for-thinking-fast-and-slow-1672f55fe647): *Cognitive Biases to Watchout For — Thinking, Fast and Slow*)

If you've had a series of *good events*, your **loss aversion** exaggerates the effect of the loss. (It is also called **loss aversion** when you exaggerate the effect of a gain after a string of losses.)

Answer (score 0):

**Selective memory** (n).

> Confirmation bias, the tendency to search for, interpret, favor, and
> recall information in a way that confirms one's preexisting beliefs or
> hypotheses. [Wiktionary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selective_memory)

> The tendency to remember only what one wants to remember [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/selective%20memory)

---

> This is because the memory we have stored in our minds about the event
> is strictly based on **selective memory** in both good and bad times.
> **Selective memory** allows us to remember certain parts of the event that has happened in the past and put aside the ones that are not so
> important to us. [Belinda Liau; *True Leaders, Part III*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/True_Leaders_Part_III/HxdIby8oDzQC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22selective%20memory%22%20bad%20events&pg=PA219&printsec=frontcover)

> It is to say that human memory is fallible. Events and people are
> remembered differently from the way they perhaps were, actions take on
> coloration, good and bad, and wishful thinking and **selective memory**
> play tricks. [John Pen La Farge; *Turn Left at the Sleeping Dog*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Turn_Left_at_the_Sleeping_Dog/R3KZK3_mL7wC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22selective%20memory%22%20bad%20events&pg=PA9&printsec=frontcover)